# How to do a Flask async post response without blocking all the service?

Tags: flask, asynchronous, server, python-requests

I have a flask[async] app that could have several sessions sending one request maximum per session to an external server.

```
import requests

@app.route('/service', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
async def service():
       try:
          get_data = requests.post(url)
                
       except requests.ConnectionError:
          print('The request has no answer')
```

Unfortunatelly, when there are several sessions in parallel, the app is waiting the response from the first request.post(url) and blocks all the service. Furthermore, the function has been defined as async.

I would like the service to continue working with other sessions, without bloquing all the session waiting for a single request.

Answer (score 0):

simple example:

```
from flask import Flask , json
import httpx

app = Flask("app")

@app.route("/",methods=['GET'])
async def get_data():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as session:
          result = await session.get(f'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
          return result.json()
   
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

you need to install httpx instead of using requests because a requests makes sync requests.

in your case it should be like:

```
from flask import Flask , json
import httpx
    
app = Flask("app")

@app.route('/service', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
async def service():
   async with httpx.AsyncClient() as session:
           result = await session.get(url)
           return result.json()
```

also you can use asycio library to write concurrent code.
note: highly recommended using Sanic for async Framework :)

Comment: Thanks. Now it sends the post correctly but it doesn't wait for the answer (HTTPError). Do you know why please?

Comment: I've added a longer timeout and it waits for the anwer. However, the server is completely bloqued and no other session is working until the answer is received. Maybe it is due to some internal process that blocks the service, including httpx. What could it be?